# Android. Problem with arabic keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, arabic

I make arabic virtual keyboard, and I have a problem.

If you write only arabic characters - all works (written right to left). But the numbers and punctuation marks are written to the right of the previous word. Although should be written to the left of the word. For example:

You write:

**word_2011** where '**_**' is space

Must be:

'**2011_drow**' (look right to left, numbers read left to right)

but is:

'**_drow2011**'

Now more interesting. If you write '**NOW**' you get

'**_drow201WON1**' (must be '**WON2011_drow**')

This is Android problem? Or is it possible to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way Android mis-implements bidi (bi-directional) logic. 
You will also have issues with arabic letters not displaying the mid and start letters correctly.

To work around the space problem you could try to insert a direction character between them see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters. This will work, but will get a square displayed instead of a space in some phones.